# EMR - Hive and Java together

Tags: java, hive, emr

I'm using Amazon Elastic-Map-Reduce.
Is it possible to run a HIVE query that uses a java code (using the Transform functionality)?

When I create a new job-flow, I need to select between a custom-jar and a hive program, while I need both ...

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by writing your own UDF (User Defined Function). Just extend a [org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic](http://hive.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDF.html) class and use your JAR like you would any other UDF JAR (import at the top, call the function).

See http://dev.bizo.com/2009/06/custom-udfs-and-hive.html for a tutorial.